# u-boot : Relocation

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, u-boot

This one is a basic question related to u-boot.

Why does the u-boot code relocate itself ?

Ok, it makes sense if u-boot is executing from NOR-flash or boot ROM space but if it runs from SDRAM already why does it have to relocate itself once again ?

Comment: This should not have been closed.

Comment: WHy is this closed ? Is this not a related question ?

Comment: It needs one more vote to be re-opened.

Answer (score 5):

This question comes up frequently. [Good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263069/1821972) sometimes too.

I agree it is handy to load the build to SDRAM during development. That works for me, I do it all the time. I have some special boot code in flash which does not enable MMU/cache. For my u-boot builds I switch CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE between flash and ram builds. I run my development builds that way routinely.

As a practical matter, handling re-initialization of MMU/cache would be a nontrivial matter. And U-Boot benefits IMO from simplicity, as result of leaving out things like that.

The tech lead at Denx has expressed his [opinion](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2004-August/006808.html). IIRC his other posts are more strongly worded than that one. I get the impression that he does not like to repeat himself.

update: *why* relocate. Memory access is faster from RAM than from ROM, this will matter particularly if target has no instruction cache. Executing from RAM allows flash reprogramming; also (more minor) it allows software breakpoints with "trap" instructions; also it is more like the target's normal mode of operation, so if e.g. burst reads from RAM are iffy the failure will be seen at early boot.

Comment: The link is not actually an answer to the question, but to what you apparently assume is the motivation behind the question.  On that subject your MMU re-initialization comment is interesting though - that platform on which I've loaded u-boot *from* u-boot without significant difficulty didn't have a real MMU.

Answer (score 3):

U-boot has to reserve 3 regions in memory that stores: 1) u-boot itself, 2) uImage (compressed kernel), and 3) uncompressed kernel. These 3 regions must be carefully placed in u-boot to prevent conflict.

However, the previous stage boot-loader, (BL2 or BL1) that brings u-boot into DRAM memory don\t know u-boot's planing on these 3 regions. So it can only loads u-boot onto a lower address in DRAM memory and jump to it. Then, after u-boot execute some basic initialization and detect current PC is not in planed location, u-boot call relocate function that move u-boot to the planned location and jump to it.

Answer (score 0):

The code of NOR flash must initialize the SDRAM, Then the copy code from Nor Flash to SDRAM, The process will copy itself, **because you could enable MMU, we will start Virtual address mapping.**