# Understand U-Boot memory footprint

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot, zynq

I don't understand what is happening in RAM when loading U-Boot. I'm working on a Xilinx Zynq ZC702 evaluation kit and I'm trying to load a Linux kernel on it using U-Boot. So I used the Xilinx tool Vivado and the SDK to generate a BOOT.bin file that is written on an SD card step by step:

- Create an HW project using Vivado,
- Generate FSBL and FPGA bitstream using the SDK,
- Create a boot image containing the FSBL + bitstream + U-Boot (I downloaded the U-Boot sources from the xilinx Git repository).

In short, I followed all the steps described on [Xilinx User Guide](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Getting+Started).

But now, before loading the kernel, I wanted to understand what was happening but I can't. According to the documentation, U-Boot, if loaded from flash, copies itself into RAM, and executes itself from there, but where ?

I searched on the web and I found that the address where U-Boot extracts itself is defined in *include/configs/zynq-common.h* by ***CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE***, which appear to be 0x400_0000.

But on an other website I saw that we can print the relocation address in debug mode, so I modified the file *common/board_r.c* and overwrote the function "*initr_announce*" to print the "*gd->relocaddr*" field. This time it appear that U-Boot uses the offset address 0x3FF3_7000.

When I use U-Boot command "md" to inspect the memory I see that the two offsets are used, and I see a sort of magic number "be00_00ea" at both locations :

```
Xilinx First Stage Boot Loader 
Release 2014.4  Feb  8 2016-14:53:56
Devcfg driver initialized 
Silicon Version 3.1
Boot mode is SD
SD: rc= 0
SD Init Done 
Flash Base Address: 0xE0100000
Reboot status register: 0x60400000
Multiboot Register: 0x0000C000
Image Start Address: 0x00000000
Partition Header Offset:0x00000C80
Partition Count: 3
Partition Number: 1
Header Dump
Image Word Len: 0x000F6EC0
Data Word Len: 0x000F6EC0
Partition Word Len:0x000F6EC0
Load Addr: 0x00000000
Exec Addr: 0x00000000
Partition Start: 0x000065D0
Partition Attr: 0x00000020
Partition Checksum Offset: 0x00000000
Section Count: 0x00000001
Checksum: 0xFFD14B7E
Bitstream
In FsblHookBeforeBitstreamDload function 
PCAP:StatusReg = 0x40000A30
PCAP:device ready
PCAP:Clear done
Level Shifter Value = 0xA 
Devcfg Status register = 0x40000A30 
PCAP:Fabric is Initialized done
PCAP register dump:
PCAP CTRL 0xF8007000: 0x4C00E07F
PCAP LOCK 0xF8007004: 0x0000001A
PCAP CONFIG 0xF8007008: 0x00000508
PCAP ISR 0xF800700C: 0x0802000B
PCAP IMR 0xF8007010: 0xFFFFFFFF
PCAP STATUS 0xF8007014: 0x00000A30
PCAP DMA SRC ADDR 0xF8007018: 0x00100001
PCAP DMA DEST ADDR 0xF800701C: 0xFFFFFFFF
PCAP DMA SRC LEN 0xF8007020: 0x000F6EC0
PCAP DMA DEST LEN 0xF8007024: 0x000F6EC0
PCAP ROM SHADOW CTRL 0xF8007028: 0xFFFFFFFF
PCAP MBOOT 0xF800702C: 0x0000C000
PCAP SW ID 0xF8007030: 0x00000000
PCAP UNLOCK 0xF8007034: 0x757BDF0D
PCAP MCTRL 0xF8007080: 0x30800100

DMA Done ! 

FPGA Done ! 
In FsblHookAfterBitstreamDload function 
Partition Number: 2
Header Dump
Image Word Len: 0x0001BA12
Data Word Len: 0x0001BA12
Partition Word Len:0x0001BA12
Load Addr: 0x04000000
Exec Addr: 0x04000000
Partition Start: 0x000FD490
Partition Attr: 0x00000010
Partition Checksum Offset: 0x00000000
Section Count: 0x00000001
Checksum: 0xF7EAFAC8
Application
Handoff Address: 0x04000000
In FsblHookBeforeHandoff function 
SUCCESSFUL_HANDOFF
FSBL Status = 0x1


U-Boot 2015.07 (Feb 11 2016 - 10:24:28 +0100)

Model: Zynq ZC702 Development Board
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  ECC disabled 1 GiB
MMC:   zynq_sdhci: 0
SF: Detected N25Q128A with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Model: Zynq ZC702 Development Board
Net:   Gem.e000b000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
zynq-uboot> md 0x4000000
04000000: ea0000be e59ff014 e59ff014 e59ff014    ................
04000010: e59ff014 e59ff014 e59ff014 e59ff014    ................
04000020: 04000060 040000c0 04000120 04000180    `....... .......
04000030: 040001e0 04000240 040002a0 deadbeef    ....@...........
04000040: 0badc0de e320f000 e320f000 e320f000    ...... ... ... .
04000050: e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000    .. ... ... ... .
04000060: e51fd028 e58de000 e14fe000 e58de004    (.........O.....
04000070: e3a0d013 e169f00d e1a0e00f e1b0f00e    ......i.........
04000080: e24dd048 e88d1fff e51f2050 e892000c    H.M.....P ......
04000090: e28d0048 e28d5034 e1a0100e e885000f    H...4P..........
040000a0: e1a0000d eb0005dc e320f000 e320f000    .......... ... .
040000b0: e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000    .. ... ... ... .
040000c0: e51fd088 e58de000 e14fe000 e58de004    ..........O.....
040000d0: e3a0d013 e169f00d e1a0e00f e1b0f00e    ......i.........
040000e0: e24dd048 e88d1fff e51f20b0 e892000c    H.M...... ......
040000f0: e28d0048 e28d5034 e1a0100e e885000f    H...4P..........
zynq-uboot> md 0x3ff37000
3ff37000: ea0000be e59ff014 e59ff014 e59ff014    ................
3ff37010: e59ff014 e59ff014 e59ff014 e59ff014    ................
3ff37020: 3ff37060 3ff370c0 3ff37120 3ff37180    `p.?.p.? q.?.q.?
3ff37030: 3ff371e0 3ff37240 3ff372a0 deadbeef    .q.?@r.?.r.?....
3ff37040: 3f312628 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000    (&1?.. ... ... .
3ff37050: e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000    .. ... ... ... .
3ff37060: e51fd028 e58de000 e14fe000 e58de004    (.........O.....
3ff37070: e3a0d013 e169f00d e1a0e00f e1b0f00e    ......i.........
3ff37080: e24dd048 e88d1fff e51f2050 e892000c    H.M.....P ......
3ff37090: e28d0048 e28d5034 e1a0100e e885000f    H...4P..........
3ff370a0: e1a0000d eb0005dc e320f000 e320f000    .......... ... .
3ff370b0: e320f000 e320f000 e320f000 e320f000    .. ... ... ... .
3ff370c0: e51fd088 e58de000 e14fe000 e58de004    ..........O.....
3ff370d0: e3a0d013 e169f00d e1a0e00f e1b0f00e    ......i.........
3ff370e0: e24dd048 e88d1fff e51f20b0 e892000c    H.M...... ......
3ff370f0: e28d0048 e28d5034 e1a0100e e885000f    H...4P..........
zynq-uboot>
```

Why U-Boot need those two offsets ? And what is the real memory footprint of U-Boot ? And more generally where can I put my kernel to be sure that it will not overwrite something ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### u-boot relocation on ARM architecture

Here is the whole sequence for two-stage boot process:

1. ROM-code reads SPL (from `MLO` file on SD card) to `CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE` address. This address is usually in SRAM which doesn't need to be initialized to be functional (as opposed to RAM). ROM-code jumps to SPL code.
2. SPL configures RAM, then reads u-boot (from `u-boot.img` file on SD card) to `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` RAM address (which is usually in the begin of RAM) and run it
3. u-boot relocates itself to `gd->relocaddr` RAM address (which is usually in the end of RAM) and jumps to relocated code
4. Now we are ready to boot kernel

For single-stage boot you don't have SPL, usually only `u-boot.bin` file is used. In that case you only have steps 3 and 4.

There are two cases regarding relocation (as described in [doc/README.arm-relocation](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.arm-relocation;h=645b3746c8a88fe25f7c9a33cd9b8b17aa7b5a57;hb=HEAD)):

1. `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE != gd->relocaddr`: relocation will be performed
2. `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE == gd->relocaddr`: relocation will not be performed

In your case you see that relocation was performed (as `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE != gd->relocaddr`).

So, addressing your question:

> Why U-Boot need those two offsets ?

The reason behind that relocation is described in [u-boot ARM relocation task](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/TaskAddArmRelocation):

> ...**we can measure the actual size of memory present on the board, and then relocate U-Boot to the very end of the RAM, leaving nearly the whole RAM usable as one big contiguous area for "applications" like loading Linux kernel, ramdisk, etc.**

Indeed, if you look to code you can see that `gd->relocaddr` is the end of RAM minus monitor code (U-Boot) size:

```c
gd->relocaddr = gd->ram_top;
...
gd->relocaddr -= gd->mon_len;
```

Also some extra memory reserving can be performed. For example, on my platform (TI DRA7XX EVM), I can see next functions beeing called:

```
setup_dest_addr()
reserve_round_4k()
reserve_mmu()
reserve_uboot()
```

The actual relocation is done just after `board_init_f()` call.

**arch/arm/lib/crt0.S**:

```
bl board_init_f
...
b relocate_code
```

**arch/arm/lib/relocate.S**:

```
ENTRY(relocate_code)
```

Now it's easy to answer your next question:

> what is the real memory footprint of U-Boot ?

Before relocation U-Boot resides at `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE`. After relocation U-Boot resides at `gs->relocaddr`.

Regarding your last question:

> where can I put my kernel to be sure that it will not overwrite something?

Since U-Boot was relocated to the end of RAM you can theoretically use any RAM address to put kernel to. But take a look at `CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS` definition in `include/configs/zynq-common.h`:

```
"sdboot=if mmcinfo; then " \
        "run uenvboot; " \
        "echo Copying Linux from SD to RAM... && " \
        "load mmc 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && " \
        "load mmc 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && " \
        "load mmc 0 ${ramdisk_load_address} ${ramdisk_image} && " \
        "bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}; " \
    "fi\0" \
```

From there you can see that you should load kernel to `${kernel_load_address}`, which is `0x2080000`:

```
"kernel_load_address=0x2080000\0" \
```

See rest of that definition for other constants.

### bdinfo command

You can find `bdinfo` command useful: relocation address along with other useful information can be found using `bdinfo` command from U-Boot shell. For example for DRA7XX EVM:

```
=> bdinfo

DRAM bank   = 0x00000000
-> start    = 0x80000000
-> size     = 0x60000000
TLB addr    = 0xDFFF0000
relocaddr   = 0xDFF5D000
reloc off   = 0x5F75D000
irq_sp      = 0xDEF3CEE0
sp start    = 0xDEF3CED0
```

From here you can see that:

- RAM starts at `0x80000000`
- RAM size is `0x60000000`
- ...so RAM end (`gd->ram_top`) is `0x80000000 + 0x60000000 = 0xE0000000`
- relocation address is `0xDFF5D000`
- reserved memory for relocation is `0xE0000000 - 0xDFF5D000 = 652 KB`
- monitor (U-Boot) size is approximately `TLB addr - relocaddr = 0xDFFF0000 - 0xDFF5D000 = 588 KB`

See also:

[1] [u-boot : Relocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719986/u-boot-relocation)

[2] [what is the use of SPL (secondary program loader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244862/what-is-the-use-of-spl-secondary-program-loader/31252989#31252989)

[3] [commit that adds ARM relocation support to u-boot](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=commit;h=f1d2b313c9eb6808d30c16a9eb5251240452a56c)

Comment: So if I set #define CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE to 0x3ff3_7000, u-boot will be copied directly from flash to RAM at this address without relocation ? And for you the kernel address is 0x0208_0000, but why not 0x8000_0000 since it indicates that it's the start address of your DRAM ? (And where can I put the device tree ?)

Comment: `0x02080000` is the address for your board. For DRA7XX EVM it's `0x80800000`. Please see `CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS` definition in your `include/configs/zynq-common.h` file for all addresses (kernel, device tree, ram disk).

Comment: Yes, if you set `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` to relocation address there will no be relocation performed. You can see this behavior mentioned in `doc/README.arm-relocation`. This is implemented in `relocate_code` assembler routine, see this line: `beq relocate_done /* skip relocation */`

Comment: ...But I'd recommend you not to mess with that `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` constant, at least not in production. It was done for a reason, so if you don't have strict requirement to spare that relocation -- it's better to leave it as is.

Comment: Ok thanks, it was just to understand the process ;) But there is still a problem, If I load the device tree at the address 0x200_0000 (as specified in zynq-common.h file) I get "image is not a fdt, FDT creation failed !"...

Comment: Try to run `run sdboot` command from U-Boot shell rather than doing all steps manually. As I can see from `CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS`, you should have `uImage`, `devicetree.dtb` and `uramdisk.image.gz` files on your SD card. If problem persists -- you should create a new question for it with details on that particular issue.

Comment: Yes, I have my kernel and the device tree (my ramdisk is wrapped in the kernel image) next to the BOOT.bin file, but the problem is that the environment var loadbootenv_addr is 0x200_0000 (same address that the device tree), so I put the kernel at 0x308_0000 and the DT at 0x300_0000

Comment: If you don't have to provide ramdisk address to `bootm` command, semantics should be `bootm 1 - 3`, where 1 is kernel address and 3 is device tree address. As stated in `bootm` help: `To boot that kernel without an initrd image, use a '-' for the second argument`. If both `bootm` semantics and device tree address are correct, and device tree blob itself is legit, than everything should just work.